# Where is the swarm rule in The Cypher System Rulebook?

Tags: cypher-system, content-identification

The swarm rule appears in *Numenera* on page 232, and in *The Strange* on page 260. But I can't find it in *The Cypher System Rulebook*.

**Where can I find it? If is not present in the book, why is that?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page 296 mentions in an aside

> GM Intrusion: A swarm of twelve ordinary  rats—each level 1, but acting like a level 3 swarm—is summoned by the high-
>   pitched squeaking of a giant rat.

But otherwise no, the text is not to be found (I searched my PDF for "swarm" and other relevant phrases, like "group of"). You'd have to ask @Montecookgames why, but given that aside, it seems like it got cut by oversight.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the *Ninth World Bestiary*, on page 13.

> The GM can take any creature and
>   have a group of six to ten of them
>   attack en masse as a single creature
>   that is two levels higher, inflicting
>   double the original creature’s normal
>   damage. So thirty level 3 abhumans
>   might attack as five level 5 mobs.

Answer (score 0):

Although not using the term 'swarm', the rules for multiple enemies working together can be found on page 349 of the Numenera Core Book:

> As a general rule, for every four creatures working together, treat them as one creature with a level equal to the highest of them plus 1, with a minimum of a +2 damage bonus. So a level 4 bandit who has three level 3 allies could team up and attack one foe as a level 5 NPC.