# Is this Multiple Enemies rule a house rule?

Tags: house-rules, content-identification, numenera, cypher-system

I found online a *[cheat sheet](https://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/35046/roleplaying-games/numenera-system-cheat-sheet-final-version)* stating the following rule for Multiple Enemies/Swarm:

> 4 creatures = 1 creature of highest level + 1, minimum +2 damage bonus

That is different from the official one for the Swarms (explained in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/85200/3171)).

I cannot find this rule on the Numenera rulebook nor the Cypher System rulebook. Is a house rule, or a failure of mine in the Intellect task to find it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I contacted the author of that cheat sheet through e-mail and they directed me to page 349 of the Numenera core book:

> As a general
>   rule, for every four creatures working together, treat
>   them as one creature with a level equal to the highest
>   of them plus 1, with a minimum of a +2 damage
>   bonus. So a level 4 bandit who has three level 3 allies
>   could team up and attack one foe as a level 5 NPC.

The author similarly noted that this is re-printed on page 344 of Numenera Discovery.

Comment: Excellent. For those who wonder, for the italian translation of Numenera this rule can be found on page 321.